# calling derived class member function

Tags: c++

```
class MyArray
{
private:
    string name;
    string message;
    string sentence;

public:
    MyArray(string name) : name(name) {};
    virtual void display() { cout<<message<<endl; };
    MyArray();
    ~MyArray();
};

//derived class
class MyArrayWithStamp : public MyArray
{
public:
    string message;

    MyArrayWithStamp(string sentence)
    {
        sentence = sentence;
    }

    virtual void input(string name)
    {
        message = name;
    }


};

int main()
{

    MyArray *p = new MyArrayWithStamp("Apple");
    p->input("This is a long long long long ... text");
    p->display();

    return 0;
}
```

What I want to do is:

1. `MyArrayWithStamp` should keep a string. ("Apple")
2. Inside `MyArrayWithStamp`, there is a virtual function named `input()`, and input function has a parameter `sentence("This is a long long long long ... text")`, this should be passed to the parent class.
3. Inside the parent class, there is a virtual function named `display()`, this function will display the string inside `MyArrayStamp("Apple")` and the sentence parameter ("This is a long long long long ... text").

If I build and run this code, i get this message :

> error: no matching function for call to 'MyArray::input(const char [39])'.

But isn't there input function in `MyArrayWithStamp`?

What can be the problem?

Comment: That's not how virtual functions work. `MyArray` does not know that `input()` exists. In order for a pointer to have any function callable on it, the class of that pointer must declare that function. Virtual functions let you override the base implementation, but there still has to be a base declaration. When declaring such functions, use the specifiers `virtual` in the base and `override` in the derived class, and the compiler warnings will soon tell you what thinko you made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems:

- you can't access private members of `MyArray` from `MyArrayWithStamp`. You should use `protected` or a `public` method.
- `MyArray *p`: p is a pointer to variable of type `MyArray` that doesn't have any member function called `input`. You should either define `input` in `MyArray` or declare `MyArrayWithStamp *p = new MyArrayWithStamp("Apple");`

The correct code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class MyArray
{
private:
    string name;
protected:
    string message;
    string sentence;

public:
    MyArray(string name) : name(name) {};
    virtual void display() { cout << message << endl; };
    MyArray() {};
    ~MyArray() {};
};

//derived class
class MyArrayWithStamp : public MyArray
{
public:

    MyArrayWithStamp(string sentence)
    {
        this->sentence = sentence;
    }

    virtual void input(string name)
    {
        this->message = name;
    }


};

int main()
{

    MyArrayWithStamp *p = new MyArrayWithStamp("Apple");
    p->input("This is a long long long long ... text");
    p->display();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C++ is statically typed language. So, if you have pointer `p` with type `MyArray*` compiler can call only methods of this class and it parents when using this pointer. `input` doesn’t belong to `MyArray` class.

Try to change code to `MyArrayWithStamp *p = ...` and all will compile fine.